# height 100% and min-height collapsing in chrome

Tags: css, html

I am trying to stretch a inner child div to the remaining size of the window, while limiting it to a min-height. Please see this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/AxmB8RoYKY95GQqOVG7h?p=preview

The child div stretches to the remaining space and it does not get smaller than the min-height as expected but only in Firefox and IE. When I test this in Chrome the stretched div collapses when the min-height is hit.

Is there something wrong with the styles or is there a work around?

This is the browser versions I tested on:
Firefox: 27, IE 11 and Chrome 32

Comment: I now tried it in Safari and it's the same result as in chrome so it is something to do with web-kit.

Comment: question not clear !!!

Comment: @sanjeev The question is how to fix the style so that the div behaves in chrome the same way as it does in Firefox or IE. Or why do the div collapse in chrome when the min-height is reached.

Answer (score 0):

if it works in the other browsers it may be a chrome only item, since there is no 'Standard' in html every browser has it's own pre-built css in place. Most of them look standard, but sometimes they cause issues.

You could try performing a css reset with this code, That worked for me on a project i was working on last year.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: I added the reset to the page but it did not fix the problem, tanks anayways